# How to assign theme in base class using master page?

Tags: asp.net, class, themes, radix

I am trying to assign a theme based on browser type.  I would like to do this in a base class so it would only need to be in one place (I am using a master page).  I coded the following but the "OnLoad" here is performed before the "Page_PreInit".  This needs to go in Page_PreInit, but why isn't it firing?

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class MyBaseClass
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Assign the CSS Theme based on the Browser Type
    If (Request.Browser.Type = "IE8") Then
        Page.Theme = "Standard-IE8"
    Else
        Page.Theme = "Standard"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub

End Class
```

Then, I have my Login page coded to inherit the base class:

```
Partial Class Login
'Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Inherits MyBaseClass

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Thank you,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *override* `OnPreInit` in the base class.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'Assign the CSS Theme based on the Browser Type
        If (Request.Browser.Type = "IE8") Then
            Page.Theme = "Standard-IE8"
        Else
            Page.Theme = "Standard"
        End If
        MyBase.OnPreInit(e)
    End Sub
```

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210502055611/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx) for more information on using a custom base class.

Comment: That is a winner.  Thanks a bunch!